# Kotlin Coroutine - Keeping Channel Send Event Synchronous

Tags: kotlin, channel, coroutine

I have a class which listens to events coming from a socket at a very fast pace. I would like to feed these events into a coroutine `Channel`. The following code is used:

```
class MyClass(channel: Channel<String>) : ... {

 ...

  override onMessageReceived(message: String) {
     MyScope.launch {
        channel.send(message)
     }
  }

}
```

This does not work since sometimes the events come in so fast that they end up getting posted out of order due to the `launch` spawning a new coroutine and everything happening in parallel. How can I ensure the order of the `send` is synchronous?

I tried `newSingleThreadContext` which did work however it is considered experimental and has a note saying it will be removed eventually. I am looking for a more solution that is more correct and complete.

Comment: Did you try to call offer() instead of send()? That's not a suspending function so you don't need to spawn a coroutine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of launching the `send`s in parallel, you should use a `Channel` with a capacity of Channel.UNLIMITED, and have `onMessageReceived` use `offer` instead of `send`.

This is a lot cheaper than launching a new job for each send, and the channel will preserve the order